# Keras clarification on definition of hidden layer

Tags: python, keras

I am following a tutorial on building a simple deep neural network in Keras, and the code provided was:

```
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Is the first `model.add` line to define the first hidden layer, with 8 inputs in the input layer? Is there thus no need to specify the input layer except for the code `input_dim=8`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right.

When you're creating a `Sequential` model, the input "layer"`*` is defined by `input_dim` or by `input_shape`, or by `batch_input_shape`.

`*` - The input layer is not really a layer, but just a "container" for receiving data in a specific format.

Later you might find it very useful to use functional API models instead of sequential models. In that case, then you will define the input tensor with:

```
inputs = Input((8,))
```

And pass this tensor through the layers:

```
outputs = Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu')(inputs)
outputs = Dense(8, activation='relu')(outputs)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(outputs)
```

To create the model:

```
model = Model(inputs,outputs)
```

It seems too much trouble at first, but soon you will feel the need to create branches, join models, split models, etc.